# aligning CSS3 pseudo :before shape with list image

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to align a css shape with the list icon.

Right now it looks like this:

[image]

But It should look like:

[image]

I tried using position: absolute; relative; and margin, still nothing. Heres a live test:

http://jsfiddle.net/fzSrL/

css:

```
.services-info ul {}
.services-info ul li {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 40px 0;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 115px;
    width: 263px;
}

.services-info ul li:before {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 100px solid red;
    border-bottom: 50px solid transparent;
}

.services-info ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
    list-style-image: url(../images/fb-icon.png);
}

.services-info ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
    list-style-image: url(../images/twitter-icon.png);
}

.services-info ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
    list-style-image: url(../images/yt-icon.png);
}
```

How can I align them together? Or would images as corners be a better option?

Comment: `:before` is not new in CSS3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `position: relative` on the `li`s, and then `position: absolute` on the "arrows" (`li:before`).

You can then precisely position the arrows with a combination of `top`/`left` and a negative `margin-top`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/fzSrL/2/

This technique is explained here: http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/

Comment: Negative margins will work fine. Regarding *other* things you're using: `:before`/`:after` won't work in IE7: http://caniuse.com/css-gencontent, and `nth-of-type` doesn't work in IE until version 9. It all works in IE9 just fine. *(rhyme rhyme)*

Comment: Your `"It should look like"` image does not contain paragraphs, so I didn't think they were relevant to the problem. I'll take another look.

Comment: Oops, sorry. The paragraphs are pushed down when the triangle is there

Comment: The `list-style-image`s are what's causing the offset from the top. Does that help? If you want me to solve this, then I have one further question. Should those icons on the left be links? If so, then a good fix would be to stop using `list-style-image`, and to add some `a` elements.

Comment: I tried to fix the images, but nothing seems to work. And no there not links.